# Tagger and Channel Forms — import from simple text field?

Tags: devdemon-tagger, tagger

I'm using an API to pre-populate EE entry forms, and one of the fields is a Tagger field. How do I take my comma-separated string of plain-text tags and turn the into something the Tagger field will accept?

I know Tagger has an Import feature, but I'd love to able to do this at the entry level, instead of having to go in and process tags manually each time.

If not, is there another tagging add-on that will allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! I figured it out. When creating a new entry, use this field, instead of calling the proper Tagger field:

```
<input name="gallery_location[single_field]" type="text" value="">
```

Then use double pipes to separate your values, and Tagger will accept the submission.

```
<input name="gallery_location[single_field]" type="text" value="New York||Amsterdam">
```